Getting more details debugging. How to get full strings?
Running a Lisp script through
emacs -Q --script script.el

I am getting an error starting as follows:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Cannot include file /media/iago/5e020581-9609-49e5...")
  error("Cannot include file %s" "/media/iago/5e020581-9609-49e5-a45d-db9b4a41d6ff/i...")

I would like to know which is the file which cannot be included, but, as you see, its address is abbreviated. Is there some way I can get it fully displayed?
